# MySQL Query Redesign

Tags: mysql

I have the following query selecting everything from the `notes` table where the input(ex: bob) is not in the `orders` table.

```
SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE notes.customer_email NOT IN 
(SELECT customers_email_address FROM orders) 
AND ((customer_phone LIKE '%bob%') 
OR (customer_name LIKE '%bob%') 
OR (customer_email LIKE '%bob%')) 
AND customers_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY `customer_email` 
ORDER BY `customer_name` 
DESC LIMIT 50
```

This fat boy of a query is taking ~80 seconds on my dev machine and ~7 seconds on the live server.

Two questions:

1. What did I do wrong with this query? (I need to learn from my mistakes)
2. How can I improve this query?

Comment: If possible don't use `LIKE` in that way.

Comment: Put an `EXPLAIN` in front of your query and then post the results here.

Comment: Only `SELECT` the columns you need! Don't ever `SELECT *`.

Comment: The table structures would be helpful too.

Comment: I was going to post the EXPLAIN results but fthiella answered my question.  I appreciate all the response and help!

@njk Just researched * verses selective columns. I see your point thank you.

Comment: @bxmas13 +1 for the research and effort done to improve your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  `notes` left join orders
   on notes.customer_email=orders.customers_email_address
WHERE
  orders.customers_email_address is null
  AND notes.customers_id IS NULL 
  AND ((customer_phone LIKE '%bob%') 
        OR (customer_name LIKE '%bob%') 
        OR (customer_email LIKE '%bob%')) 
ORDER BY `customer_name` 
DESC LIMIT 50
```

they are usually faster than the IN/NOT IN clause. And also, I am not sure why you put a group by clause here.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answered my question perfectly.  The query is running at .03 seconds!